# Cant get image preview of twitch streams

Tags: image, preview, twitch

I want to show the preview images of streams, but I cannot get it work.

```
function get_url_contents($url){
    $crl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($crl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($crl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $ret = curl_exec($crl);
    curl_close($crl);
    return $ret;
}

$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?limit=25&amp;offset=0&amp;q=Age%20of%20Empires%20II:%20The%20Conquerors ";
$json = get_url_contents($url); 
$json = json_decode($json);

foreach($json->streams as $stream) { 
    echo '<img alt="" style="float: left; width: 50px; padding-right: 7px;" src="' . $stream->channel->logo . '" />';
    echo $stream->channel->status . '<br />';
    echo $stream->channel->display_name . ' esta jugando ' . $stream->channel->game . '.<br />';
    echo '<img alt="" src="' . $stream->preview . '" /> <br />';
    echo '<a href="http://www.twitch.tv/' . $stream->channel->name . '">Ver en vivo</a>';
    echo '<hr />';
}
?>
```

Im trying to show information of stream online, if i take out this sentece echo `echo '<img alt="" src="' . $stream->preview . '" /> <br />';` everything work good, but if i put, it doesnt work . and this error show Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in  on line 25 , the line 25 is the sentence i put.

Comment: Could you explain what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Im trying to show information of stream online, if i take out this sentece echo '<img alt="" src="' . $stream->preview . '" /> <br />'; everything work good, but if i put, it doesnt work .  and this error show Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\AppServ\www\phpBB3\streams.php on line 25 , the line 25 is the sentence i put.